# App cannot send REST requests on W10Privacy-treated laptop

Tags: networking, windows-10, laptop

I'm using a Windows 10 company laptop which has been treated with W10Privacy. On this laptop I have to use an app which uses REST requests to communicate with a company server.

Unfortunately this doesn't work. The app immediately throws an error that the server is not reachable and that I should check my internet connection. But the internet connection is fine. Browsers do work, eMail works, `ping` works, etc. And on my Windows 10 PC at home the app also works fine. But the app on the laptop does not, even from the same network.

I already tried disabling the firewall on the laptop. The laptop and my PC don't run a separate antivirus, other than the Windows Defender.

After nothing of the basic solutions worked, we came to the conclusion that it must be related to W10Privacy. But there are so many configuration possibilities and testing the obvious things like ...

```
Privacy - > Do not let apps read or send messages (text or MMS)
Telemetry -> Block Microsoft servers, to which telemetry data will be sent              
Services -> Disable the dmwappushsvc service
```

... didn't work either. Also the `Firewall` tab has no ticks set.

Did somebody here encounter a similar situation and maybe can point me to the right W10Privacy setting? I'm going nuts ...

Thank you!

Comment: Is the company server perhaps hosted on Azure?

Comment: @grawity As far as I know they don't use Azure. It is a domain like `https://ws.company.de` and different ports like 8443, 4200 and 5200.